# Using two scanners.. one for integer, one for double which is causing my code not to work.

Tags: java

Question: How do I fix this? The code works when I feed the values, but when I use a scanner to read values it stops reading input after I enter the number of cities and throws a run time exception.

I tried to use two scanners instead of one.. One for double and one for integer and Im pretty sure thats not how you do it because then I see "lossy conversion from double to int". Can someone help? FYI, I am a UX architect and Im new to this. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Centralcity {


        public static void main(String[] args){


            int numcities;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            double shortest = 0;
            double distance1 = 0;
            double distance2 = 0;
            int closestX1=0, closestX2=0, closestY1 =0 , closestY2 = 0;

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the number of cities: " );
            numcities = scanner.nextInt();


            double[] xcor=new double[numcities];
            double[] ycor=new double[numcities];
            double[][] distance= new double[numcities][numcities];
            double[] sumdistance= new double[numcities];
            double[] temp= new double[numcities];


                //numcities = 5;
                //double xcor[]=new double[] {2.5,5.1,1,5.4,5.5};

                //double ycor[]=new double[] {5,3,9,54,2.1};

          for(int i = 0; i<numcities; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<numcities; j++)
                {      
                System.out.println("Enter coordinates of the city:");
                xcor[i]=scanner.nextDouble();
                xcor[j]=scanner.nextDouble();
                ycor[i]=scanner.nextDouble();
                ycor[j]=scanner.nextDouble();
                }
                }

             for(int i = 0; i<numcities; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<numcities; j++)
                {                    

                distance[i][j]=Math.pow((Math.pow(xcor[i]-xcor[j], 2)) + (Math.pow(ycor[i]-ycor[j], 2)), 0.5);
                sumdistance[i]+=distance[i][j];
                }

            }

             temp=sumdistance;
              double temp1;

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < (temp.length -i); j++)
            {
                        if(temp[j-1] > temp[j])
                {
                    temp1 = temp[j-1];
                    temp[j-1]=temp[j];
                    temp[j]=temp1;
                }
            }
        }   

      double finl=0;
        for(int i = 0; i <numcities; i++)

             {
                 if(sumdistance[i]==temp[0])
                    {
                        finl=i;               

                    }               
            }
             System.out.println("The Central City coordinates are: " +xcor[finl]+","+ycor[finl]);

        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the exception? They exist for a reason.

Comment: The input data would also be helpful

Comment: I think I see only one `Scanner`...

Comment: There's nothing in this code that should give that error message, as far as I can tell. Is this the actual code that gives you that error? Can you post the actuall error message?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're telling us that the error you receive is "lossy conversion from double to int". You are not able to convert a double value to an int value. Either your input data or the way you read in the data should change.

A Q&A on why you can't convert double to int: [Why can int/byte/short/long be converted to float/double without typecasting but vice-versa not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389595/why-can-int-byte-short-long-be-converted-to-float-double-without-typecasting-but)

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable finl to int type. like:

```
 int finl=0;
    for(int i = 0; i <numcities; i++)

         {
             if(sumdistance[i]==temp[0])
                {
                    finl=i;               

                }               
        }
         System.out.println("The Central City coordinates are: "       +xcor[finl]+","+ycor[finl]);
```

It will work.